# How to pass C# variable in php url (Html e-mail button)

Tags: c#, php, html, email, url-parameters

My App send Html email that contain `button` to the user, using Gmail API. Button URL must have in-build user's email address (value of `toAddress`) .

My question is how to combine C# variable  `toAddress` and php URL passing so that destination link looks like Examle:

```
<a href = http://mypage.com/Email-list.php?email=VALUE_OF_toAddress
```

After that i will save `toAddress` value to database.

Here is `sendEmail` method with `htmlbody`

```
public static string sendEmail(string emailTo)
    {
        string fromEmailPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailPassword"];
        string fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LastLogin"];
        string fromPassword = fromEmailPassword;


        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(emailTo, emailTo);

        string subject = "Player";
        string body = "";

        try
        {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };


            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);

            message.Subject = "Player";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;

            htmlBody = @"
                        <html lang=""en"">
                            <head>    
                                <meta content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"" http-equiv=""Content-Type"">
                                <title>
                                    Player
                                </title>
                                <style type=""text/css"">
                                </style>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                            <div class="button">
                                <a href = http://mypage.com/Email-list.php?(-??????-) target =_blank style=""display: block; text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;color: #ffffff; background-color: #3F2409; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; max-width: 132px; width: 92px;width: auto; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 20px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;mso-border-alt: none"">
                                <span style = ""font-size:16px;line-height:32px;"" > Yes, I Agree</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            </body >
                        </html >
                        ";


            message.Body = htmlBody;

            {
                smtp.Send(message);
                return "Sent";
            }

        }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String interpolation on your string literal `htmlBody` like this `$@"<text_here"`. So essentially putting the `$` before the `@` then using `{}` to surround your `toAddress` variable in the href.

Like this:

`$@"<whole_lot_of_html>  href=""http://mypage.com/Email-list.php?email={toAddress} <rest_of_your_html>"`

I don't know how your data layer is set up given your example, so I can't give you pointers on how to save the `toAddress` to the database. However, if you still have access to your `toAddress` variable after sending the email you should be able to handle that here. That being said, you may want to pose another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
string htmlBody = string.Format("<html lang=\"en\"> <head> <meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"> <title> Player </title> <style type=\"text/css\"> </style> </head> <body> <div> <a href=\"http://mypage.com/Email-list.php?email={0}\" target=\"blank\" style=\"display: block; text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;\"> <span style=\"font-size:16px;line-height:32px;\">Yes, I Agree</span> </a> </div> </body > </html >",emailTo);
```

Html button with email address (C# variable `emailTo`) attached to URL

`<html><body>div><a href=\"http://mypage.com/Email-list.php?email={0}\">Submit</span> </a> </div> </body > </html >",emailTo);`

Comment: That's definitely one way to do it. Both string interpolation and Format strings basically accomplish the same thing.